# Should we always require users to show what they tried?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am looking at [Forming a list out of two lists with certain pattern in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614239/forming-a-list-out-of-two-lists-with-certain-pattern-in-python) now. As one comment points out, the question didn't include any code showing what the user tried at first, so it was bashed with negatives and close votes (for "being too broad" somehow, even if the user, in my opinion, made a good effort in explaining the problem and I think it was clear and concrete enough). Anyway, the user posted his code later and got reasonable answers.

My point is, is it always really *necessary* that a user posts some code showing what they tried? (I'm talking about question where posting code makes sense in the first place, obviously). In this case, if you look at the code the user posted (which was, one could say, quite misguided) and the answers, they are nothing alike at all. What was the point on the user putting any code here exactly? Okay, sure, it shows effort and/or research, and we can tell they are not trying to get homework done for free, but honestly, unless the answer is a fix over the posted code, or at least points out what is wrong with it, the question is just as valid as before. What is more, I would say (because I've been there a long, long time ago on occasion) in some cases more novice programmers don't even know how to begin to solve a problem, or the most they can post is a blatantly blind guess. And the fact that the question looks too easy or "homework-like" may arise suspicion, but doesn't really make it a bad question by itself.

What I mean is that I feel there are cases where you either know how to at least approach a problem or you don't, and if you don't any code you may post will be basically useless. I think it's legit to ask users to post what they tried, but maybe sometimes it is also legit to simply answer "I don't even know where to begin", and a well-written question posing a clear and concrete problem shouldn't be lynched for that.

Comment: `What was the point on the user putting any code here exactly?` It shows readers what the OP does and doesn't understand, so they know exactly what they do and don't need to explain.  If someone posts a solution that's 5% of the way there before they got stuck, the reader knows that the author doesn't understand basically anything about the problem, and the whole thing needs to be explained, if they post a solution that's 95% of the way there, an answerer only needs to show how to fix the missing piece(s).

Comment: ` some cases more novice programmers don't even know how to begin to solve a problem` And in that case, needing to explain *everything* about the *whole* problem is going to be Too Broad, so if we're forced to assume that they don't know *anything* about the problem, and need to start from the smallest of building blocks needed to construct the answer, that's beyond the scope of what can be posted in an SO answer.  On the other hand, if they can demonstrate an understanding of most of what's needed, such that explaining the missing pieces isn't covering much, it's not too broad.

Comment: My personal opinion is this- No there doesn't **have to be code** to prove effort. The way a question is formed directly relates to the subject matter and the amount of effort a person puts in will be reflected **in the way they ask**. If the question seems like it was lazily constructed, it probably was and the assumption is going to be that it was.

Comment: As Jason says, you don't *need* code to solve the problem I've mentioned above.  There are other ways to show what aspects of a problem you do and don't understand, and what you need explained to you, besides just showing an incomplete solution.  It's just that showing an incomplete solution is often (but not always) an extremely effective means of accomplishing this; often much easier and more effective than trying to explain in English what you've done, what you understand, and what you don't understand.  This is why good questions that contain no code exist, they're just much less common.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for your comments. The accepted (and quite upvoted) answer to the question of which this has been marked a duplicate of (with my own vote) says "If you're closing questions solely because they don't contain code, you're doing it wrong", which was my main concern with the close and down votes in the question at hand (as I saw it, others could think the question was still bad). It also has interesting numbers about questions with no code.

Comment: related: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt